# Moving a Wordpress site to HTTPS Everywhere - do external links need to https too?

Tags: https, wordpress

I want to make a Wordpress site fully HTTPS Everywhere - but have a number of plugins installed, do I need to make sure that all my external links use href https too?

Answer (score 1):

Only things you have on the site - like images from third party sites etc need to be https. Like Instagram pictures for example. If you are simply linking out to another site then that does not matter. If you use chrome you will see a green padlock if everything is working properly.